# select key/value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im getting json values from http service for each id.. trying to give a drop down with list of names and ids as key to store . If I have this in my html

```html
<select>
<option ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

this in my controller

```js
 $http.get('/api/v1/secure/admin/groups/v/users').success(function(response) {
  var j=[];
  var k=[];

  $scope.data=[];

  $scope.vId=[];
  $scope.vName=[];

  console.log(response[0]._id)//getting 1st id
  console.log(response[0].name.prefix+" "+response[0].name.first+" "+response[0].name.last)//getting name

  for (var i =0; i<response.length; i++) {

    k=(response[i]._id);
    j= (response[i].name.prefix+" "+response[i].name.first+" "+response[i].name.last);

    console.log("list of visit manager: "+$scope.vManagerName+"  id  "+$scope.vManagerId);

  };

  $scope.data={
    $scope.vManagerId.push(k) : $scope.vManagerName.push(j)
  }

});
```

but its undefined ...please help..*thanks in advance*

Comment: what is response structure?

Comment: What is undefined and please provide the structure of response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to map on controller as you are doing wrong

Try like this

View

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="d._id as d.name.prefix+' '+d.name.first+' '+d.name.last for d in data">   
</select>
```

CTRL

```
$scope.data=response
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/2dwtu2us/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this within your loop:

```
$scope.data.push({"key":k, "value" :j}) ;
```

Then you'll have this in your html

```
<select>
<option ng-repeat="kv in data"  value="{{kv.key}}">{{kv.value}}</option>
</select>
```